# Dictionary keys get automatically sorted if keys are numbers

Tags: javascript, sorting, dictionary

```
var a = ['a1', 'b2', 'd4', 'c3'];
var dict = {};

for(var i=0; i<a.length; ++i) {
dict[(a[i].match(/\d+/)[0])] = a[i];
}
console.log(dict);

for(var i=0; i<a.length; ++i) {
dict[a[i]] = a[i].match(/\d+/)[0];
}
console.log(dict);
```

In the first case, where keys are numbers, we have output with dictionary keys sorted.

But in second case, where keys are not numbers, we have output with a dictionary keys in the order they were added!

Is this some hidden feature, I mean is it reliable every time?

Comment: Arrays retain their order, objects do not (dictionary is not a JS term)

Comment: While not explicitly specified, browsers _usually_ return object keys in insertion order. However, by no means should you rely on that always being the case as there is no requirement for them to do so.

Comment: In both the cases, i was asking about dictionary and not array.

Comment: @Viki and both comments do address that.

Comment: The ones you are pointing is the second case where the objects need not be displayed in the same order. Ok!
But in the first case the numbers are neatly sorted out! I've tested it with many samples and it worked!

Comment: `is it reliable every time?` - No, it is not. It is not specified in what order keys should be returned by the spec, so there is simply no guarantee the browser will do the same thing you expect it too.

Answer (score 0):

In your example `a` is an [`array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and `dict` is simply an [`object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

The order of the item of an `array` is preserved.

There is no specification about the order of the `object` attributes but the order is often the one in which they were defined...if the structure is kept unchanged. There is no guarantee about the order thus.

Comment: Please see the edited question to avoid any confustion